# 2d array issues- I get error : expression must have pointer-to-object type (opencv, CUDA)

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

question:
   Hello I get the error:expression must have pointer-to-object type
    This happens at all nine lines where I do the addition inside the kernel....
    I know it has to do with initializing the array....please help solve this issue...
    should I change something inside my cudamalloc function? or  am I missing  something
    Please help me!

include parameters

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

#define DIM 512
#define K 16

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



//CUDA function prototype. It takes output image and input image

cudaError_t  blurWithCuda_shared(Mat&, const Mat&);
```

Here is my kernel

```
// CUDA GPU Kernel (working with Shared Memory)
__global__ void gpuBlurWsharedMemory( unsigned char *dst, const unsigned char *src)
{
    //  Calculate the index of the pointers based on pixel location for each thread
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

     __shared__ float shared [K][K];


    shared [threadIdx.x ][threadIdx.y]=  (src[threadIdx.x][ threadIdx.y] + 
                        src[threadIdx.x -1][ threadIdx.y -1]+
                        src[threadIdx.x -1][ threadIdx.y]+
                        src[threadIdx.x -1][ threadIdx.y + 1]+
                         src[threadIdx.x][ threadIdx.y - 1]+
                         src[threadIdx.x][ threadIdx.y + 1]+
                        src[threadIdx.x +1][ threadIdx.y - 1]+
                        src[threadIdx.x + 1][ threadIdx.y]+
                        src[threadIdx.x+ 1][ threadIdx.y +1])/9.0;

        __syncthreads(); 

        dst [offset]=      shared [threadIdx.x ][threadIdx.y];

}
```

My main

```
int main()
{



    // This is the cudaError code that functions may return to troubleshoot
    cudaError_t cudaStatus ;            

    //Process first image
    Mat inputImage = imread ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Dimitrios\\My Documents\\My Pictures\\Images\\Lighthouse_Gray.jpg");


    Mat gpuBlurredImage_shared (DIM, DIM, CV_8UC1);

    if (!inputImage.data)
        printf ("Image didn't load properly!\n");
    else 
    {
        //Show original first image
        imshow ("Original Image", inputImage);


    //Blur first image with CUDA in parallel (using shared memory)
    cudaStatus= blurWithCuda_shared(gpuBlurredImage_shared, inputImage);

     if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) 
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Cuda Failed!");
    return 1;
    }

        imshow ("Blurred on GPU with Shared Memory", gpuBlurredImage_shared);   
        cvWaitKey(0);
    };




    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

My helper function

```
// Helper function for using CUDA to perform image blurring in parallel (using shared memory). 

cudaError_t blurWithCuda_shared(Mat &blurredImage, const Mat &input)
{
    //GPU side ouput and input pointers
    unsigned char *dev_ptrout = 0;  
    unsigned char *dev_ptrin = 0;   

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;

    cudaStatus = cudaEventCreate(&start);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaEventCreate failed!");
        goto Error;
    }
        cudaStatus = cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaEventCreate failed!");
        goto Error;
    }
    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
}

    // Allocate GPU buffers for the buffers
    // Allocate the input pointer on the device. Note the size of the pointer in cudaMalloc
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc( (void**) & dev_ptrin, sizeof(unsigned char) * input.rows * input.cols);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate the output pointer on the device. Note the size of the pointer in cudaMalloc
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc( (void**) & dev_ptrout, sizeof(unsigned char) * blurredImage.rows * blurredImage.cols);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input data from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_ptrin, input.data, sizeof(unsigned char) * input.rows * input.cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    dim3 Grid=(DIM/K, DIM/K);
    dim3 Block=(K,K);

    //Launch a kernel on the GPU 
    // Measure the time it takes to complete the kernel
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);

    gpuBlurWsharedMemory <<<Grid, Block>>>(dev_ptrout, dev_ptrin);

    cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    printf("Time leapsed on CUDA Shared Memory with syncthreads()= %3.2f ms\n", elapsedTime);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }


    //Copy output data from GPU buffer to host memory. use cudaMemcpy
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(blurredImage.data, dev_ptrout, sizeof(unsigned char) * blurredImage.rows * blurredImage.cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_ptrin);
    cudaFree(dev_ptrout);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the `src` pointer to your kernel as a single (`*`) (i.e. "1D") pointer.  You can't reference it with two subscripts:

```
src[][]
```

like you are doing in those 9 lines in your kernel:

```
src[threadIdx.x -1][ threadIdx.y -1]+
```

I would suggest making sure you are passing `src` as a proper 1D single pointer (`*`) to the kernel, then using pointer/index arithmetic to reference it in the kernel:

```
src[(threadIdx.y -1)*DIM + (threadIdx.x -1)]
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: should I also make the shared array as a 1d?
or how can I keep it as a 2 d array? what changes can I make? I am lost

Comment: You can leave the shared array as-is.

Comment: Thank you. so, is this going to work?

shared [threadIdx.y ][threadIdx.x]= 

          src[(threadIdx.y) + (threadIdx.x)]+
          src[(threadIdx.y -1) + (threadIdx.x -1)]+
          ............
          src[(threadIdx.y +1) + (threadIdx.x +1)]/9.0;

  __syncthreads(); 

 dst [offset]=      shared [threadIdx.x ][threadIdx.y];

Comment: No I don't think so.  You need to multiply one of the subscript values by the width of the `src` array.  Take a look at where I put the `DIM` in my answer, and search on "flatten 2D array" to get hints about how to do the subscript arithmetic.

Comment: can i ask you one more question?
what changes should I make if I wanted to keep src[][] as a 2d array?
this is where I am confused.

I ask because right now the output is a window with black and grey stripes

Comment: do a search in the upper right hand corner on "CUDA 2D array".  It makes the code more complicated.

Comment: so you mean as it is now (your code) is not going to work? I need to flatten the array?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really following your questions.  What do you mean "my code" ?  The code I wrote in my answer is an example.  You have to interpret it and apply it correctly in your code.  Your array is probably already 1D.  There is no need to flatten a 1D array.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't allow me to post another answer in less than 8 hours...I will wait and post what I have and all I want to know is if the syntax is correct...
Thank you again